# MySQL: How to get changes of last UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a database application with MySQL and PHP. At this moment I'm trying to get the changes caused by the last UPDATE. My first way to solve the problem is

- getting the 'old' state with SELECT
- Doing the changes with UPDATE
- getting the 'new' state with SELECT
- comparing the arrays with php

These are three mysql-connections...

Is there any way to shorten this?

Comment: Store the original state when you load the form locally then compare what you're sending in the update also locally? No reason to invlove MySql in figuring out the changes.

Comment: Since you basically have the intended "new" state in memory anyway, you could save at least the second SELECT. As long as your UPDATE does not report any error, you can pretty much rely on the fact that the database state will be what you think it is. To say more, it would be nice to know what exactly your are planning to do with that delta.

Comment: Do you need only to determine how many rows were affected, or is a detailed data comparison required?

Answer (score 3):

You could do an [before update trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) that will push an entire copy of the record to a history table that also contains additional state data you wish to store (updated date, user etc.)

This way you will have a complete revision history of what happened with what records and it should happen transparently. only think to remember is you should drop any unique constraints from the history table.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you how I do that,

When I update a row, firstly I get which row I'm updating and I call them `active records`. Then I compare each column of `active records` with the form fields. That's how I know which column has changed.

And if you want to store changed columns, create `history` table that would be like;

```
id        (for primary key)
tablename (which table i'm updating)
recordid  (which row i'm updating)
column    (which columns has been changed)
oldvalue  (active record value)
newvalue  (form value-updated value)
date      (obvious)
user      (who did this change)
```

After that, you can use your imagination for structures how you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following hack using variables:

```
update table set 
col=(@oldValue:=col),col=newValue
where id=1234;
select @oldValue;
```